# There is class Inside SWC with long and weird name

Tags: flash, actionscript, swc

Inside compiled swc I noticed weird class with a long name (like _a7d23055bd84520600d28a112a8757b8d20e65493798dd7985f7fdd9920c552a_flash_display_Sprite).

This is a class inherited from Sprite class.
Screenshot http://my.jetscreenshot.com/2520/20140515-fdxd-42kb

Maybe somebody know for what is that?
And there are two methods inside:
  native public function allowDomainInRSL(... rest):void;
  native public function allowInsecureDomainInRSL(... rest):void;

For what they?

Or maybe somebody know where I should dig.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using RSL (runtime shared libraries) in your project? Probably [it will help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf674ba-7fff.html).